# Не могу выполнить функцию Update

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Customer.NumberOfActiveSubs = (SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN Subs.SubEndDate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as ActiveSubs
    FROM Subscription as Subs
    INNER JOIN Customer as Cust
        ON Subs.CustomerID = Cust.CustomerID
    WHERE Cust.CustomerID = Subs.CustomerID
    Group by Cust.CustomerID)
```

Ошибка:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Формулируйте саму задачу, а не только свою попытку её решить. И укажите точно СУБД, в том числе точную версию. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: @Akina, подскажите, как можно избавиться от **Group by** так, чтобы обновляло все строки не одинаково, а разными значениями, которые возвращаются из запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправьте в запросе
WHERE Cust.CustomerID = Subs.CustomerID
на
WHERE Cust.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы гений